# Get local asmx WebService from Android emulator

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, soap, asmx

I'm try to open a method that return a SOAP from a local asmx WebService in Android emulator.

The method returns that:

`<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">`

`[{"Id":1,"Codigo":"asdv","Descricao":"dadada","Fornecedor":{"Id":1,"Codigo":1,"RazaoSocial":"a vida é boa","NomeFantasia":"IBM","TipoEmpresa":1,"CnpjCpf":"98.768.839/9287-27","Comissao":"12,12","Contato":[{"Id":1,"Nome":"Edgard ","Email":"edgard.ibm@ibm.ibm","Telefone":"9696-9696","Fax":"9837-2374","DDD":"23","Celular":"9876-71988","Nextel":"8123-4723"}],"ContatoTela":null,"Endereco":{"Id":2,"Pais":null,"UF":"SP","CEP":"06010-110","Cidade":"Osasco","Bairro":"JD do cu","Rua":"Rua Doutor Antônio José Luciano","Numero":302,"Complemento":"loko"},"Site":"ibm","Parcelamento":"","TipoEmpresaString":"Fornecedor"},"Ipi":23,"St":12,"Ncm":22,"Icms":221,"QuantidadeEstoque":99,"PrecoTela":null,"Preco":122.12},{"Id":2,"Codigo":"123","Descricao":"teste","Fornecedor":{"Id":2,"Codigo":2,"RazaoSocial":"uhu","NomeFantasia":"DELL","TipoEmpresa":1,"CnpjCpf":"23.942.834/9823-94","Comissao":"23,42","Contato":[{"Id":2,"Nome":"nome","Email":"email","Telefone":"2384-2374","Fax":"7283-4728","DDD":"11","Celular":"7237-42387","Nextel":"9872-3498"}],"ContatoTela":null,"Endereco":{"Id":3,"Pais":null,"UF":"SP","CEP":"09882-778","Cidade":"sampa","Bairro":"jdjdjd","Rua":"dahahahah","Numero":203,"Complemento":"ahshduashduh"},"Site":"hahhahahahaha","Parcelamento":"","TipoEmpresaString":"Fornecedor"},"Ipi":12,"St":12,"Ncm":12,"Icms":12,"QuantidadeEstoque":998,"PrecoTela":null,"Preco":2222.22},{"Id":3,"Codigo":"234","Descricao":"novo","Fornecedor":{"Id":1,"Codigo":1,"RazaoSocial":"a vida é boa","NomeFantasia":"IBM","TipoEmpresa":1,"CnpjCpf":"98.768.839/9287-27","Comissao":"12,12","Contato":[{"Id":1,"Nome":"Edgard ","Email":"edgard.ibm@ibm.ibm","Telefone":"9696-9696","Fax":"9837-2374","DDD":"23","Celular":"9876-71988","Nextel":"8123-4723"}],"ContatoTela":null,"Endereco":{"Id":2,"Pais":null,"UF":"SP","CEP":"06010-110","Cidade":"Osasco","Bairro":"JD do cu","Rua":"Rua Doutor Antônio José Luciano","Numero":302,"Complemento":"loko"},"Site":"ibm","Parcelamento":"","TipoEmpresaString":"Fornecedor"},"Ipi":12,"St":22,"Ncm":2,"Icms":21,"QuantidadeEstoque":9,"PrecoTela":null,"Preco":202.2},{"Id":4,"Codigo":"333","Descricao":"asdasd","Fornecedor":{"Id":2,"Codigo":2,"RazaoSocial":"uhu","NomeFantasia":"DELL","TipoEmpresa":1,"CnpjCpf":"23.942.834/9823-94","Comissao":"23,42","Contato":[{"Id":2,"Nome":"nome","Email":"email","Telefone":"2384-2374","Fax":"7283-4728","DDD":"11","Celular":"7237-42387","Nextel":"9872-3498"}],"ContatoTela":null,"Endereco":{"Id":3,"Pais":null,"UF":"SP","CEP":"09882-778","Cidade":"sampa","Bairro":"jdjdjd","Rua":"dahahahah","Numero":203,"Complemento":"ahshduashduh"},"Site":"hahhahahahaha","Parcelamento":"","TipoEmpresaString":"Fornecedor"},"Ipi":2,"St":1,"Ncm":11,"Icms":31,"QuantidadeEstoque":0,"PrecoTela":null,"Preco":230}]`

`</string>`

I tried to open by two ways:

`10.0.3.2:49498/WebServiceApp.asmx/ObtemListaProdutos`

that link works little slow, but finally the browser from emulator shows:

"Webpage not available
The webpage at http://10.0.3.2:49498/WebServiceApp.asmx/ObtemListaProdutos might be temporalily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web addres"

or

`10.0.2.2:49498/WebServiceApp.asmx/ObtemListaProdutos`

and now its fast:

"Bad Request - Invalid Hostname
HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid".

i think if it isnt work on the emulator browser, on the application it isnt too.

am i correct?

whats wrong?

Sorry about my english, i'm still learning.

thanks!

Comment: wall of text! Please format your posts.

Comment: If you go to http://localhost:49498/WebServiceApp.asmx/ObtemListaProdutos from the computer, it works fine?